# Enable nested KVMs

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, boot-loader, nested-virtualization

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS right now. The hostisng provider uses KVM for virtualization of their VPS'. I am trying to install another KVM virtual machine on my VPS (aka nested KVMs). I've read this short guide for how to enable it:

https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Nested_Guests

Apparently all I need to do to enable nested KVM instances is apply this flag at bootup of my purchased VPS:

> -cpu host

So my question is, how can I set a bootup flag? Edit a config file for the bootup related stuff, or pass a parameter to the reboot command?

Comment: This requires assistance from the VPS provider.  In particular they need to load `kvm-intel` or `kvm-amd` modules, and _they_ control the `-cpu` flag that starts your VPS.

Comment: I see. Ok that is interesting because I spoke to them earlier with the same question, and they simply told me it could be done and provided me the guide I have. So I kinda assumed that the rest could be taken care of on my end. But Okay, I'll contact them. Thank you.

Comment: They may already have done those parts :-)

Comment: Ya based on my convo yesterday, it seems they had updated the config file for their specific CPU aka adding options kvm-intel nested=Y in /etc/modprobe.d/kvm_intel.conf. So they'll just need to add the flag.